# Check location is in a pre-defined area (Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cllocationmanager

I am currently building an iOS app and would like to use the device's location data to determine what train station they are currently in. How can this be done using swift?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @Michas I have got it to display the location in labels on screen and in the console.